# HTTp/tomcat base64 encoding

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, base64

I am using base64 to encode hashes that are to be sent over HTTP to a tomcat server. Does anyone know how to url encode base64 so that it works properly with HTTP and tomcat?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which library you use for Base64-encoding, but basically there's a version of Base64 that is [URL-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

If you use Apache Commons Codec, you can use [Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] bytes)](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a standard base64 which has +, / and = for padding the string. There is no such thing a version of Base64 that is URL-safe.
I already looked into that website. Does anyone else have other ideas. thanks.

Comment: @Jack "There is no such thing a version of Base64 that is URL-safe" Did you follow the first link in my answer?